# How to create a grid style homepage for website?

Tags: grid

can anyone tell me how to do like a grid layout homepage please?[how to code it or where to find  this information.
the squares should respond/change colour or image when the mouse hovers over to show they can be clicked. i'd like to be able to have different sized and shaped squares too.

cheers

pic related
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZNbk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use boostrap ui components
E.g.
http://www.bootply.com/70929